# MS Access SQL "INSERT INTO" statement produces date in wrong format despite correct regional setting

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, formatting

My computer's regional date setting is dd/mm/yyyy. I am using MS Access. I would like to insert records into a database using the SQL `INSERT INTO` statement. When I try to insert a date using the `#dd/mm/yyyy#` syntax, and view the resulting record in the table after, it turns out the record displays the date in the format mm/dd/yyyy instead, but ONLY for the first 10 days of the month; if the day is 11 onwards, the record displays dd/mm/yyyy as intended.

For example if in SQL code I input `#09/02/2022#`, the table will display the record with the date 02/09/2022 instead. However if my SQL code is`#11/02/2022#`, then the correct order 11/02/2022 is shown in the record.

Please help.

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way this works?

You don't have to care, know, or think about the users regional format settings.

So, if you drop some control on a form? Just make sure that control is set to a date type format. Your done.

BUT ONE big whopper:

IN ANY AND ALL cases, your string based date format MUST be in USA format. Or you can use ISO date format.

```
 dim MyDate   as Date

 MyDate = me.InvoiceDate
```

So, now we have a internal format date variable. How to insert into a table?

```
dim strSQL  as string

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblInvoice (InvoiceNum, InvoiceDate, InvoiceAmount " & _
         "VALUES (1234, " & quDate(MyDate) & ",50)"
```

So, you ALWAYS format the date value into USA format.

You can type that format command over and over, but that fast becomes tiring.

so, I use a little helper function:

```
Public Function quDate(dt As Date) As String

   quDate = "#" & Format(dt, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"

End Function

Public Function quDateT(dt As Date) As String
  
     ' return formatted date  with time
     
     quDateT = "#" & Format(dt, "mm\/dd\/yyyy HH:NN:SS") & "#"    
     
  End Function
```

So, you don't have to care about the date and regional format, but for a in-line SQL insert command that you build in code? Yes, you MUST convert to USA format of mm/dd/yyyy.

So, you can display dates in any format. For forms, for reports - not a problem.

However, the ONLY exception here is your code that builds a insert statement. That date string format must be #mm/dd/yyyy#.

Or, ISO:

```
 #yyyy-mm-dd#
```

So, either format is fine, but it is a hard and fast rule that you must conform to.

So, from a text box on a form, if not data bound, then you want to ensure that the text box is set as a date type text box (fomrat date).

then in code:

```
dim strSQL as string

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFun (BirthDate) " & _
        "VALUES (#" & format(txtDate,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#)"

currentdb.Execute strSQL
```

Or, if you have that helper function, then this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFun (BirthDate) " & _
        "VALUES (" & qudate(txtDate) & ")"
```